# Javascript how to define an object by array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I recently started learning html/javascript and I want a temporary object to be filled with one of the objects from an array based on the current page number.

```
loadnextpage();
function loadnextpage() {
    var curpage = allcontent[pagenumber];
    pagenumber++;
    changeDiv('title', '<span>' + curpage.pageNumber + '</span>' + curpage.title);
}
```

But when I try to run the code it keeps giving me an error message that `curpage` is undefined, after that it keeps running and thus the last line of code gives an error, when I ask for `curpage.pageNumber`. After that it stops running the code.

[image clipping of my code with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPc3R.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

edit:
here is the entire code:

```
var pagenumber = 0;
var receipt = [];
var price = 0;
var text = '{"page": [{"pageNumber": "1","title": "kies je formaat","optionName": "size","option": [{"text": "klein","value": "small","extraPrice": "100"},{"text": "middel","value": "medium","extraPrice": "200"},{"text": "groot","value": "large","extraPrice": "300"}]},{"pageNumber": "2","title": "kies je kleur","optionName": "colour","option": [{"text": "rood","value": "red","extraPrice": "10"},{"text": "groen","value": "green","extraPrice": "20"},{"text": "blauw","value": "blue","extraPrice": "30"}]}]}';
var allcontent = [];
allcontent = JSON.parse(text);
var imgpath = 'img/';
loadnextpage();
function loadnextpage(){
    var curpage = allcontent[pagenumber];
    pagenumber++;
    changeDiv('title', '<span>' + curpage.pageNumber + '</span>' + 
curpage.title);
    var radiobuttons = '';
    var radiobuttonid = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < curpage.option.length; i++) {
        var curradio = curpage.option[i];
        radiobuttons += '<label><div class="selection-wrap">';
        radiobuttons += curradio.text;
        radiobuttons += ' <input type="radio" name="';
        radiobuttons += curpage.optoinName;
        radiobuttons += '" value="';
        radiobuttons += curradio.value;
        radiobuttons += '" id="';
        radiobuttons += curpage.optoinName;
        radiobuttons += '_';
        radiobuttons += curradio.value;
        radiobuttons += '"></div></label></br>';
        radiobuttonid.push(curpage.optoinName + '_' + curradio.value)
    }
    changeDiv('choices', radiobuttons);
    for(var i = 0; i < radiobuttonid.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(radiobuttonid[i]).onclick = function(){
            receipt[pagenumber-1] = curpage.option[i];
            for(var i = 0; i < receipt.length; i++){
                price += receipt[i].extraPrice;
            }
            changeImg('previewimg', imgpath + curpage.option[i].value + 
'/preview.jpg');
            changeDiv('previewprice', '<h1>&euro;' + price + ',-</h1>');
        };
    }
};

function changeDiv(id, content) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
};
function changeImg(id, img){
    document.getElementById(id).src = img;
};
```

Comment: Evidently `allcontent[pagenumber];` is undefined. What debugging have you done? What is the contents of `allcontent`?

Comment: Please include the code for filling your `allcontent` as well as `pagenumber`.

Comment: `console.log(allcontent)` and `console.log(pagenumber)` there wont be a property with pagenumber in allcontent. Besides the "normal" way to name functions and variables is to camelCase, eg: `allContent`

Comment: no thats the weird part, allcontent is an array with 2 object. As you can see here: https://imgur.com/vryNfci

Comment: @Vecro then pagenumber > 1 or pagenumber is undefined

Comment: nope, it's 0: https://imgur.com/1JarJg0

Comment: @Vecro shouldn't it be allcontent.page[pagenumber]?

Comment: @Vecro if you debug, you can open the console. The console is always in the function scope your debug point is. You can output and modify all the variables available in this scope. You will be much faster using the console while debugging.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze no it shouldn't, that is (one of many) mistakes (ugly pieces of code) on my part, pagenumber is for the code to keep track of on what page it is, while pageNumber is a piece of text to be displayed on the site

Comment: @Vecro no.. your array is named page. Type in console `allcontent.page` whlie debugging

Comment: @Vecro did it work in the end? or you  need further help?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze yes that worked! thank you very much! please submit it as an answer so you'll get rewarded and other people can find the answer easier

Comment: @Vecro no it's ok. This is a very basic question and i just helped you debug a bit. I think you can delete this question.